# Return from a function from class isn't working for button for pygame

Tags: python, pygame

For some reason, my return isn't working. This is from a tutorial. When I download the file and edit it from there it works, but if I copy and paste it from the exact file it doesn't work. Sorry, I am a beginner - open to any suggestions

The is the tutorial I used:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G8MYGDf_9ho

Code:

```
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()

WinHeight = 600
WinWidth = 900
Window = pygame.display.set_mode((WinWidth,WinHeight))
#button class
class Button():
    def __init__(self, x, y, image, scale):
        width = image.get_width()
        height = image.get_height()
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (int(width * scale), int(height * scale)))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = (x, y)
        self.clicked = False

    def draw(self, surface):
        action = False
        #get mouse position
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        #check mouseover and clicked conditions
        if self.rect.collidepoint(pos):
            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 1 and self.clicked == False:
                self.clicked = True
                action = True

        if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 0:
            self.clicked = False

        #draw button on screen
        surface.blit(self.image, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))

        return action



Good_ball_img = pygame.image.load("GoodBall.png")
Bad_ball_img = pygame.image.load("BadBall.png")


#Button instances
Good_ball = Button(100,100,Good_ball_img,2)
Bad_ball = Button(200,200,Bad_ball_img,3)

def drawwin():
    Window.fill((202,241,208))
    Good_ball.draw(Window)
    Bad_ball.draw(Window)



   pygame.display.update()




def Main():
    run = True
    while run:
        if Good_ball.draw(Window):
            print("green clicked")
        if Bad_ball.draw(Window)=="t":
            print("red clicked")
        for event in pygame.event.get():
                #quit game
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        run = False
                        pygame.quit()
                        sys.exit()
        drawwin()
        checkpress()


            
    



if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
```

Comment: Be more precise. What is not working? How is it not working? What is it supposed to happen?

Comment: first use print to see what you have in variables in different moments, and which part of code is executed. It is called `"print debuging"`. Maybe this part of code is never executed because you have wrong values in variables.

Comment: BTW: there is good rule to use `lower_case_names` for variables - ie `main()`, `good_ball`, `bad_ball` and `CamelCaseNames` only for classes`. It helps to recognize class in code. More: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: `doesn't work` is the most useless information. You have to describe problem. Don't expect that we will run code to see problem. Besides code may works correctly on our computers. We can't also read in your mind. So you have to put all details in question (not in comments)

Comment: in `draw` you check mouse position and blit image - and you run it two times - first in `if/else` and later in `drawwin` - and it seem waste of time. You should rather have two function - one only to check mouse and use it with `if`, and second only to `blit` - and use it in `drawwin`

Comment: I don't understand why you compare `Bad_ball.draw(Window) == "t"` if `draw` returns only `True` or `False`

Comment: What is happening is that it is set as true but when it is checked nothing happens

Comment: maybe it set true only when you run it in `drawwin`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code works for me if I change order - first process all events later check mouse position.

Problema can be because PyGame updates values in `pygame.mouse` and `pygame.key` only if you run `pygame.event.get()` - so it may need `pygame.event.get()` or at least `pygame.event.pump()` before other functions.

```
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            #quit game
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        if Good_ball.draw(Window):
            print("green clicked")
        if Bad_ball.draw(Window):
            print("red clicked")
```

---

**EDIT:**

In documentation for [pygame.event](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) there is

```markdown
To get the state of various input devices, you can forego the event queue and 
access the input devices directly with their appropriate modules: `pygame.mouse`, 
`pygame.key` and `pygame.joystick`. If you use this method, remember 
that pygame requires some form of communication with the system window manager 
and other parts of the platform. To keep pygame in sync with the system, 
you will need to call `pygame.event.pump()` to keep everything current.
```

---

Minimal working code - with surfaces instead images so everyone can simply copy and run it

```
import pygame
import sys

# --- constants ---  # PEP8: `UPPER_CASE_NAMES`

WINDOW_WIDTH = 900
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600

# --- classes ---  # PEP8: `CamelCaseNames`

class Button():
    
    def __init__(self, x, y, image, scale):
        width = image.get_width()
        height = image.get_height()
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (int(width * scale), int(height * scale)))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = (x, y)
        self.clicked = False

    def check_click(self):
        action = False

        # get mouse
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        left_button = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]

        # check mouseover and clicked conditions

        if left_button:
            if self.rect.collidepoint(pos) and not self.clicked:
                self.clicked = True
                action = True
        else:
            self.clicked = False

        return action

    def draw(self, surface):
        # draw button on screen
        surface.blit(self.image, self.rect)

# --- functions ---  # PEP8: `lower_case_names`

def draw_window(window):
    window.fill((202, 241, 208))
    good_ball.draw(window)
    bad_ball.draw(window)

    pygame.display.update()

# --- main --- 

pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT))

# button class
#good_ball_img = pygame.image.load("GoodBall.png")
good_ball_img = pygame.Surface((100, 50))
good_ball_img.fill((0, 255, 0))

#bad_ball_img = pygame.image.load("BadBall.png")
bad_ball_img = pygame.Surface((100, 50))
bad_ball_img.fill((255,0,0))

# Button instances
good_ball = Button(100, 100, good_ball_img, 2)  # 
bad_ball  = Button(200, 200, bad_ball_img, 3)

run = True

while run:

    # - events -
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    # - checks and updates -
    
    if good_ball.check_click():
        print("green clicked")
    if bad_ball.check_click():
        print("red clicked")

    #checkpress()

    # - draws -
    
    draw_window(window)
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)